# how to update table with filtered data in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, filter, underscore.js

I'm learning backbone.js. I'm creating a backbone app to display some data in the table. I have the table view working fine, but when I search the collection for the key entered, I do see the filtered data in the console, but it shows up like this:

```
wrapper {_wrapped: Array[14], after: function, all: function, any: function, bind: function…}
```

whereas my collection displays the data like this:

```
child {length: 30, models: Array[30], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
```

My Collection:

```
App.Collections.Faxes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Fax,
    url: '/Fax',

    search: function (key) {
        if (key == '') return this;


        var pattern = new RegExp(key, "gi");
       return _(this.filter(function (data) {

            return pattern.test(data.get("FaxRecipient"));
        }));           

    }
});
```

Also, I tried doing something like this `collection.reset(search(key))`, but has no data.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your search function, return this instead:

```
return (new App.Collections.Faxes(this.filter(function (data) {
   return pattern.test(data.get("FaxRecipient"));
})));
```

Comment: @user1828605 would you be so kind as to reward me with the bounty? I'm not sure why marking the answer as correct doesn't automatically do that.

Comment: @idebehold sorry about that. I thought it did it by marking it as an answer. Let me know if you get it or not. Thanks